Making conversion of data array to Dataframe faster with x-array and Dask
I am trying to convert an x array data array into a pandas dataframe at a faster time. without using Dask I was able to convert a data array with 17 variables of 9GB each into a pandas dataframe in around 19seconds. After implementing dask with 7 workers and 10 threads per worker (wasn't getting any better with increased workers or thread.) I was only about to make it about 3 seconds faster (16 seconds). Is there a way I could make it faster or is there something I am missing. Below is my code:
def to_csv(file):
    ds = xr.open_dataset(file)
    print(ds)
    a_point = ds.sel(latitude=15.0, longitude=-25.0)
    start = time.time()
    a_point = a_point[["stl1","stl2","stl3","stl4","sp","rmin", "rmax", "tmin", "tmax", "ssr","ttr", "str", "sshf", "tsr"]]
    a_point = a_point.unify_chunks()
    print(time.time()-start)
    df = a_point.to_dask_dataframe()
    df = df.compute()
    print(df)
    print(time.time()-start)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = Client(n_workers=7, threads_per_worker=10)
    to_csv("B/B.nc")

Please any help with explanation would be appreciated. Thanks :)

19 seconds is already uite fast! Is there any reason you'd want to use Dask if you not need it? That being said, it really depends on your data, how it is chunked at first. to_csv doesn't write anything it seems. 70 threads is a lot on a single machine, which triggers a lot of exchange when computing the Dataframe into pandas.

19 seconds is a bit fast I know but for like learning sakes I want to know if it’s possible to achieve something way faster which would be great if it was. So as for the chunking, I didn’t include the code because I was trying something new when I copied this one. But I’m chunking the data with time:auto which just automatically divides it along the time axis. I know 70 threads is a lot but it seemed to make it faster by 3 seconds. Please I would really love to know if I could make it way faster, and also to know if there’s a better way I could implement dask for my case.

Without a reproducible example this would be hard. But again, gaining speed from 19s is not a great Dask use case.
